# Curity Password flow returns `invalid_grant` with no detail

Tags: oauth, curity

I follow the official [doc](https://curity.io/resources/learn/ropc/#fnref-1) to set up `Resource Owner Password Flow` but I am getting below error with no `error_description`.

```json
{
  "error": "invalid_grant"
}
```

The client_credential flow is working which means the client_id, client_secret and host name are correct.

Does anyone know what might cause above error message?

Thank you

---

Thanks [Gary Archer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9019885/gary-archer) for his [tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68799154/10241938),  I wish I knew this two days ago.

Anyway, the issue I had was related to user management. When you are used to other OIDC providers (Auth0, Keycloak, Okta, Azure) the user management is enabled by default and account admin can manage users in the portal easily.

Curity is different. Users added under `System` -> `Administrators` are **NOT** related to token services at all.

To add new users, you need to either register new users at `https://<curity_domain>/authn/registration/<HTML_Authenticator_name>` (assuming you did not change the endpoint at `Profiles` -> `Authentication Service` -> `Endpoints`)

Or

You can enable `User Management Profile` and then use `/um-api` to add users using RestfulAPI calls. (I have yet to find a way to pass in password in the request, I guess new users might need to reset password for their initial log in)

After the new user is added, you can then use password flow.

> Again, I haven't found a way to check these user detail on Curity admin ui. I must use RestfulAPI to get users list.

I suggest Curity to add a reference of this user management part on their [tutorial](https://curity.io/resources/learn/ropc/). It is not clear (at least not clear to me) the users added on the UI can not be used for requesting tokens.

One more thing I want to mentioned is, the other providers accept `openid` as scope for password flow and return `id_token` back. Curity does not seem to accept `openid` scope for password flow.

Answer (score 0):

During development it is useful to turn on the following setting in order to get further information about errors returned from the Curity Identity Server:

- Profiles / Token Service / General / Expose Detailed Error Messages

You will then get a more useful error message such as one of these:

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Provided username and password could not be authenticated."}

{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"No valid scope was requested."}
```

Then make sure your app sends the correct payload, using either of these payloads. Note that the client_id and client_secret can be sent either in the POST body or in a basic authorization header:

```sh
CLIENT_ID=ropg-client
CLIENT_SECRET=S3cret
USER_NAME=mytestuser
USER_PASSWORD=mytestpassword

curl -X POST https://localhost:8443/oauth/v2/oauth-token \
-d "grant_type=password" \
-d "client_id=$CLIENT_ID" \
-d "client_secret=$CLIENT_SECRET" \
-d "username=$USER_NAME" \
-d "password=$USER_PASSWORD" \
-d "scope=profile"

curl -X POST https://localhost:8443/oauth/v2/oauth-token \
-u "$CLIENT_ID:$CLIENT_SECRET" \
-d "grant_type=password" \
-d "username=$USER_NAME" \
-d "password=$USER_PASSWORD" \
-d "scope=profile"
```

Please post back if this does not enable you to solve your problem.

**USER MANAGEMENT**

Sounds like you understand how this works. The users in the admin UI are just for that component, similar to the built in `admin` user. To create an application user with a well known password just send a `password` field alongside the `userName` field. Here are a couple of guides with some examples:

- [User Management with SCIM](https://curity.io/resources/learn/managing-users-with-scim/)
- [SCIM 1.1 Data Source](https://curity.io/docs/idsvr/latest/developer-guide/data-sources/scim-1-1-backend.html)

**OPENID SCOPE**

The resource owner password grant is an [OAuth](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-1.3.3) flow and not part of [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html), so the `openid` scope is not used and an ID token is not returned. If this is causing you any specific problems, let me know and I'll suggest alternative options for meeting the same goals.

The other providers you mention may have extended the OAuth behavior for ROPG, though at Curity we aim to be very standards based.

Comment: Hi Gary, I posted my reply on my original question as it is quite long. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hi Gary, it is all good now. I was just doing some testing and try to formalize a workflow with as many IDPs as I can. The behavior difference is more of an unexpected result rather than giving me any problems. Thanks again for your help.